# Convert timestamp to datenum

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have the following timestamp: `20111122051342.582000`

I'm using the following code to convert the timestamp to datenum, but with this I'm loosing the millisecons

```
time.mktime( ( datetime.datetime.strptime( rows['TStamp'], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f" ) ).timetuple() )
```

For `20111122051342.582000` I'm getting `1321935222.0` How can I improve the code above to get more accuracy datenum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strptime` does not read microseconds. Try this:

```
ymdhms, usec = rows['TStamp'].split('.')
time.mktime((datetime.datetime.strptime(ymdhms, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" ) ).timetuple()) + int(usec) / 1000000.
```

This works for six (zero-padded) digits after the decimal point.